# Avoid full table scan on a simple join using OR in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, indexing, sql-optimization

I have this schema

```sql
create table table1
(
    id        int          auto_increment primary key,
    name      varchar(2)   null,
    position  int          null,
);

create index table1_position
    on table1 (position);


create table table_2
(
    id              int auto_increment primary key,
    table1_id       int          null,
    position        int          null,
    constraint table_2_ibfk_1
        foreign key (table1_id) references table1 (id)
);

create index ix_table_2_position
    on table_2 (position);

create index table1_id
    on table_2 (table1_id);
```

So I added two index on column `position` of each tables.
Now I need to look for a range of position in BOTH table (by joining then and apply an OR query)

so I have this query

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1
    INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.table1_id
WHERE table_1.position BETWEEN 5000 AND 5500
   OR table_2.position BETWEEN 5000 AND 5500
```

But the Explain query output give me ALL (Full table scan)

```
id             1
select_type    SIMPLE
table          table_1
partitions
type           ALL
possible_keys  PRIMARY,table1_position
key
key_len
ref
rows           9929
filtered       100.0
Extra
```

If I change to an `AND` if give me the expected Range index scan

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table_1
    INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.table1_id
WHERE table_1.position BETWEEN 5000 AND 5500
   AND table_2.position BETWEEN 5000 AND 5500
```

```
id             1
select_type    SIMPLE
table          table_1
partitions
type           range
possible_keys  PRIMARY,pos_idx2
key            pos_idx2
key_len        5
ref
rows           1
filtered       100.0
Extra          Using index condition
```

But I need the `OR` statement here...How could I have mysql use a range scan index for an OR statement ? Could I improve my indexes here (I thought about a multi-values index on both `position` and `table1_id` -the foreign key, but it did'nt help and it performed a full table scan).

Comment: can you add some inserts so i can test it here in my sql fiddle ?

Comment: table_2.variant_id not reflected in table schema

Comment: @ProGu I fixed it sorry, shadowing erros

Comment: Roughly speaking, t where x or y is t where x union t where y. This post is a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. [ask] [Help] PS [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.table1_id
WHERE table_1.position BETWEEN 5000 AND 5500

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.table1_id
WHERE table_1.position NOT BETWEEN 5000 AND 5500
  AND table_2.position BETWEEN 5000 AND 5500
```

Also test

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.table1_id
WHERE NOT (    table_1.position NOT BETWEEN 5000 AND 5500
           AND table_2.position NOT BETWEEN 5000 AND 5500 )
```

Comment: I tested both, The first is OK (but I go to the @O.Jones solution by selecting first the ids).
The second one with the WHERE NOT clause I got the same performance as a OR so not really what I expected. But thank you again

Comment: @jossefaz *I go to the @O.Jones solution* That's your choice. However, I do not understand why you are satisfied with a solution in which the structure of the output rowset differs from the required one. *by selecting first the ids* ?? I cannot understand what you mean. `id` columns of the tables? I doubt... but what? *The second one .. I got the same performance* This is most likely the expected result.

Comment: Do I need the indexed in you solution ? And if yes on which column ? In both position column or composite index ?

Comment: @jossefaz This depends on the tables statistic. Create all possible composite indices which includes all columns mentioned in ON and WHERE in all possible ordering, then look at the execution plan for the index which the server decide to use. Drop it, ensure that the query execution time increases. If so then this is optimal index for this query and data statistic. Remember - huge data change may make this index less optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want to avoid the table scan for reasons of performance.

So try swapping your OR for a UNION operation.

First, get the set of `table1.id` values you need with a subquery, like so.

```
    SELECT id FROM table_1 WHERE position BETWEEN 5000 AND 5500
    UNION
    SELECT table1_id FROM table_2 WHERE position BETWEEN 5000 AND 5500
```

The second part of the UNION retrieves the table_1.id values you need from table_2, by SELECTing the FK column.

Next, use that subquery to get your rows from `table1`.

```
SELECT * FROM table_1
 WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM table_1 WHERE position BETWEEN 5000 AND 5500
    UNION
    SELECT table1_id FROM table_2 WHERE position BETWEEN 5000 AND 5500           
)
```

To make this quicker, add this compound index on table_2.

```
CREATE INDEX ix_table_2_position_table1id 
          ON table_2 (position, table1_id);
```

Notice that neither of your two single-column indexes on table2 are useful for this query.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Your example query doesn't ask for any table2 columns in your result set.

Comment: `CREATE INDEX ix_table_2_position_table1id 
          ON table_2 (position, table1_id);` Reduced the performance...do you know why ?

Comment: I don't think the query in this answer is equivalent to the query the OP wants to optimize. Or am I seeing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Performance problems with `OR` can often be solved with `UNION`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.table1_id
WHERE table_1.position BETWEEN 5000 AND 5500
UNION
SELECT *
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.table1_id
WHERE table_2.position BETWEEN 5000 AND 5500;
```

Comment: UNION [DISTINCT] causes additional combined rowset sorting for to remove duplicates which degrades the performance.

Comment: @Akina: But without it, you would create undesired duplicates. The `DISTINCT` operation is the price to pay when using `UNION` instead of `OR`.

Comment: See my answer, 1st solution. Additional condition allows to avoid excess sorting.

Comment: @Akina: Ah, yes, that seems to be a good solution.